# C suddenly messing up values in 2d array

Tags: arrays, c

My code:

```
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a;
    int b;
    char inp;
    int zx;
    int zy;
    int tab[n][n];      
    for(a = 0; a < n ; a++){
        for(b = 0; b < n; b++){
            scanf("%c", &inp);          
            switch(inp){
                case 'a':
                    tab[b][a] = 6;
                    //printf("%d\n", tab[b][a]);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    tab[b][a] = -1;
                    //printf("%d\n", tab[b][a]);
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    tab[b][a] = 9;
                    zx = b;
                    zy = a;
                    //printf("%d\n", tab[b][a]);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(a = 0; a < n ; a++){
        for(b = 0; b < n; b++){
            printf("%d ", tab[b][a]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    return 0;   
}
```

The idea is to replace the input map consisting of chars 'a', 'b',  c' with their values in int map. a =  6, b = -1, c = 9.

so an input like

```
5
aacbb
ababa
aaaaa
aaabb
bbbbb
```

should output like

```
669-1-1
6-16-16
66666
666-1-1
-1-1-1-1-1
```

When I'm inputting values in 2d array everything seems ok. Everything is ok with commented printf values, however when I try to output the whole map it's like:

```
622671 6 6 9 -1
6 -485498561 6 -1 6
-1 6 564564 6 6
6 6 6 4541512341 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 564231
```

which is clearly totally wrong. With linux I get a core dump instead of an output.
I need an explanation why is this happening.

Comment: c is not an entity so it's not doing anything to you, your code has problems.

Comment: @iharob can you point it out.

Comment: add `default: --b;` to the switch's last position.

Comment: @user3121023 works. Thank you so much.... I would have never though of that....

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no. user3121023 gave correct answer

Comment: @Vedran I also give the correct answer.

Comment: @Vedran you could have thought of that if you read [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), specifically the part where they talk about the `"%c"` specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `default` case in the switch, so when you don't handle the input value the array is uninitialized when you print it.

The first time the loop runs, there is a `'\n'` that was left by the previous `scanf()`. The `"%c"` specifier does consume it, so your first time in the loop, the value was already supplied without asking you, and since you are not handling the `'\n'` in the switch, the corresponding array element is left uninitialized.

Change

```
scanf("%c", &inp)
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &inp)
```

and it will work as you expect it.

And also, just in case add

```
default:
    tab[b][a] = 0;
    break;
```

to the `switch`, to prevent passing uninitialized values to `printf()`.